# Batch file for bioinformatic analysis

Tags: perl, batch-file, bioinformatics

**Background:**

I'm part of a group project at the university where the task is to build a server based web application integrated with a database. We're using `Apache`, `PHP` and `MySQL` and it's going great. However, we're at the part where the user is to press a button `Do Analysis` and a batch file *(.bat)* is supposed to be `activated`, go through some programs and then give a result.

Here's the idea of the batch file, but it doesn't work:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD "C:\Path\To\Directory\With\All\Programs"
START "" program1.pl [specific in parameters for program1] [infile for program1] /B /WAIT
START "" program2.exe [specific in parameters for program2] [infile for program2] /B /WAIT
START "" program3 [specific in parameters for program3] [infile for program3] /B /WAIT
@EXIT
```

**Problem:**

Some programs are in reality packages of `perl` scripts or `.exe` files and require both in parameters and infiles.

On Linux a typical command in the terminal for Program1 would be `./mugsy seq_1.fsa seq_2.fsa seq_N.fsa`, where mugsy is a big `perl` script and the files `.fsa` are the infiles for mugsy.

Program2 would be: `./FastTree -gtr -nt alignment_file > tree_file`, where `-gtr` and `-nt` are necessary in parameters for the program `FastTree`, `alignment_file` is the infile used by `FastTree`, and `tree_file` is the name of the output file.

Program3 would be something like: `figtree < infile.tre > outfile.jpg`, where `figtree` is the program using the infile and outputs a `jpg`.

**Question:**

How can I write a batch file for the above situation? Is it possible?

`START /?` gives examples of different parameter settings for `start`, but not how to put parameters for the actual program starting.

When executing `START "" FastTree.exe & infile.fasta /B /WAIT` they are opening separately and I can't find any way of opening `infile.fasta` with `FastTree.exe`.

Comment: You should put `/B /WAIT` right after `start ""`.  Check `start /?`.  And you don't need `&` before infile.fast if it is just an argument for FastTree.exe. And I would not recommend leaving the title `""` empty. You may get glitches depending on OS version.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, instead of `./mugsy seq_1.fsa seq_2.fsa seq_N.fsa`, you could do `perl mugsy seq_1.fsa seq_2.fsa seq_N.fsa`. So if I try the following (incorporating the suggestions from @wolfrevokcats), it works for me on Win 7:

```
START "program1" /B /WAIT perl program1.pl arg1 arg2 arg3
```

As for general design, having a PHP script run a Windows batch file which in turn spawns off other processes using `START` doesn't seem like the best solution to me, e.g. I'm not sure if your system is supposed to later support multiple users? However, not being a PHP expert, and without knowing more about the system you're building, I can't tell you what the better way to spawn processes from PHP is, just that you might want to look into that ☺